# Find all Laurent series of a function

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm new to the subject, all help would be appreciated !

the question is:

given $f(z)$ is an Entire function $(z \in \mathbb{C})$ , and a point $w \in \mathbb{C} $

we define the function: $g(z) = \frac{f(z)}{z-w} [eq:(1)]$

find all possible Laurent series of the function, around the points $w$ and $0$ (you can use $f(z)$ as a given).

my take:

$g(z)$ is analytic apart from the point $z=w$, and $g(z) =\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} A_n(z-w)^n$

where $An = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\cdot\int_{|z-w|=r,r>0}\frac{g(z)}{(z-w)^{n+1}}dz = [eq(1)]=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\cdot\int_{|z-w|=r,r>0}\frac{f(z)}{(z-w)^{n+2}}dz =$[Cauchy's integral formula] = $ \frac{f^{(n+1)}_{(w)}}{(n+1)!}$

Same method for around the point 0 with two seperate series, one for the region |z| > w and |z| < w

I really don't think that this is the way to go with this question but as I said I really don't know what else to do,
thank you !